# How to print a string from address and size

Tags: string, go, pointers, character, memory-address

I want to print a string from address by for loop.
Below is the code that I wrote, but it gives different results when running normally and when debugging.

How can I print each char of str sequentially by address of str.

Plss help me. Tks you so muchhhh <3

This is my code!!!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    str := "Hello, World!"
    startAddr := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&str)) // Get the address of the string variable

    for i := 0; i < len(str); i++ {
        ptr := (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(startAddr + uintptr(i))) // Calculate the pointer address
        fmt.Printf("%c", *ptr)                                  // Dereference the pointer to get the character
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to get? Print each character from the string or the address of each character? have you tried `for range` ?

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC i wanna print each charactar from str. But i wanna print  value by address of string, don't use for for range from str.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your attempt doesn't work is because `&str` returns the address of the string *header*, not of the string's *data*. If you want the address of the string's data you need to first convert `&str` into a string header, and then access the data through the header. You can use the declared [`reflect.StringHeader`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.20.4#StringHeader) to do this, **just make sure you read its documentation and understand what it says**.

```golang
func main() {
    str := "Hello, World!"
    header := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&str))

    for i := 0; i < len(str); i++ {
        ptr := (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(header.Data + uintptr(i)))
        fmt.Printf("%c", *ptr)                                  
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/kniSJyM7DX5

Comment: Thank you so much, it answered all my questions!